# Why does rails prefix html ids with underscore notation and can it be changed?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, naming-conventions

After some research I had begun to start to name all my html divs using hyphens because I read that method carried the most benefits ([Naming "class" and "id" HTML attributes - dashes vs. underlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696864/naming-class-and-id-html-attributes-dashes-vs-underlines)).  Now I realized why I was using underscores before and that's because rails uses them!

For example:

```
<%= select('test', 'foo', ........)
```

will generate

```
<select id="test_foo"........>
```

omitting `'test'` gives

```
<select id="_foo".............>
```

as we can see, rails uses underscores when automatically prefixing/concatenating HTML ids.  I was wondering why rails uses the underscore instead of a hyphen and if there's anyway to change this?  Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's related with conventions, where the underscore is used as separator. You should not think about change it because Rails is a very opinionated framework, and the best advise you can get is to stick with conventions. If you are trying to circumvent them, probably you are doing something wrong. Rethink it!