# How can I get the value of radio buttons with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

My current code gets all the data from a form then outputs it to the console as an Array (I'm testing a contact form). All the data it returns is correct but the value of the radio button is always the same.

html:

```
<form class="form1" action="form.php" method="post">
<div class="form-sect">
    <div class="formb-check">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="formb-small">
        <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="ID: 00000000" class="formb-small">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-sect">
    <div class="formb-srv">
        <div class="formb-check">
            <input type="radio" name="server" id="server-1" value="Srv 1"><label for="server-1">Server 1</label>
            <input type="radio" name="server" id="server-2" value="Srv 2"><label for="server-2">Server 2</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message....."></textarea>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit Report</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('form.form1').on('submit', function() {
var that = $(this),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    type = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};

that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
    var that = $(this),
        name = that.attr('name'),
        value = that.val();

    data[name] = value;
});

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data,
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});

return false; });
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['id'], $_POST['server'], $_POST['message'])){
    print_r($_POST);
} ?>
```

In the array I'm using for testing the value of the radio button is always the second value used, in this code it is Srv 2. Like this: 
[server] => Srv 2

Comment: multiple radio buttons and inputs may have same name and you are looping on all elements (not checked elements) so you always get the value of last element in a family. I suggest using `serialize()` instead  not  inventing the wheel again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery get value of selected radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622336/jquery-get-value-of-selected-radio-button)

Comment: generally it is a bad idea to have dash separated names like the id's `server-1`

Comment: @techie_28 , I'm not aware of this, care to back that up with a source?

Comment: @JonP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696864/naming-class-and-id-html-attributes-dashes-vs-underlines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should serialize the form like this:

```
$('form.form1').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems to refresh the page and not print anything?

Comment: ok, I fixed the page refreshing but that code console logs the entire document. Any ideas?

Comment: @Will it will log whatever the server returns. You didn't show us everything it returns, I think - we can't see what the rest of your PHP script does. But that's not related directly to your original question

Comment: Tried the edit you just made but its still logging all the code inside the <html> tag on that page

Comment: You might need to change the ajax type to GET and edit your PHP script to read the GET attributes.

Comment: Got it working! Forgot I removed a line of code when I was testing different responses I got from here. Thanks @BramV :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for "checked" on radio buttons (and check boxes)

```
that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {    
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    var notCheckOrRadio = !$(this).is('[type=radio],[type=checkbox]') ;
    if( notCheckOrRadio || $(this).is(':checked')) {
       data[name] = $(this).val();
    }
});
```

Note, while this answers the question as asked, you should us [Bram's updated approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57176747/4665).

Comment: This would be more helpful if you exclude `type="checkbox"` too.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour , true, I was trying to keep is simple, but you have a point

Answer (score 0):

Every time you are getting server 2 because in jquery `$.each` will replace second value with first one.

N:B - Don't use $.each in this case and  be specific because later if new fields will come then it will be problem example checkboxes and all.

N:B- Don't use `return false` always use `e.preventDefault();`

You need to check checked radio button. Remove the unnecessary lines of code. Please follow the below example

```
   $('form.form1').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            data = {'name':$('[name="name"]').val(),'id':$('[name="id"]').val(),'server':$('[name="server"]:checked').val(),'message':$('[name="message"]').val()};
            $.ajax({
                url: 'form.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType:'json',
                data: data,
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Actually this is not optimal, if you add a new form element, you have to then code it in. If you use serialize, as [Bram suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57176747/4665) (the best option), or identify the check boxes and and radio buttons, [as in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57176804/4665), you don't have to change the javascript code.

Comment: serialize is not the best option beacuse then you really need to unserialize data in case of json

Comment: the code you have mentioned that is not standard way